# godaddy's ssl certificate with GoLang

Tags: ssl, go, https

I'm wondering how to use godaddy's ssl certificate with GoLang Https server.

currently I'm using the following code:

```
srv := &http.Server{
    Addr: httpsPortStr,
    Handler: n,
    ReadTimeout: time.Duration(config.CfgIni.ReadTimeout) * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout: time.Duration(config.CfgIni.WriteTimeout) * time.Second,
}
err := srv.ListenAndServeTLS(<CERTIFICATE_FILE>,<PRIVATE_KEY_FILE>)
```

I still have `sf_bundle-g2-g1.crt`. how do I add it to the chain of certificates ?

## update

@Vonc's answer is really helpful, i'm just missing one last thing.
I'm using http.Server instance in order to change ReadTimeout and WriteTimeout parameters. how can I do this with the tls ?

My previous code for this:

```
srv := &http.Server{
    Addr: httpsPortStr,
    Handler: n,
    ReadTimeout: time.Duration(config.CfgIni.ReadTimeout) * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout: time.Duration(config.CfgIni.WriteTimeout) * time.Second,
}
err := srv.ListenAndServeTLS(config.CfgIni.CertificateFile,config.CfgIni.PrivateKeyFile)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see a [full example here](https://gist.github.com/ncw/9253562) in the [`file-server-go`](https://gist.github.com/ncw/9253562#file-server-go) section.
The chain of certificate should be loaded in a [`x509.NewCertPool()`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#NewCertPool)

```
cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("certs/server.pem", "certs/server.key")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("server: loadkeys: %s", err)

}
certpool := x509.NewCertPool()
pem, err := ioutil.ReadFile("certs/ca.pem")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to read client certificate authority: %v", err)
}
if !certpool.AppendCertsFromPEM(pem) {
    log.Fatalf("Can't parse client certificate authority")
}

config := tls.Config{
    Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
    ClientAuth:   tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert,
    ClientCAs:    certpool,
}
config.Rand = rand.Reader
service := "0.0.0.0:8000"
listener, err := tls.Listen("tcp", service, &config)
```

In your case, `ioutil.ReadFile("sf_bundle-g2-g1.crt")`.

> I'm using http.Server instance in order to change ReadTimeout and WriteTimeout parameters

```
server := &http.Server{
    Addr:      "0.0.0.0:8000",
    TLSConfig: tlsConfig,
    ReadTimeout: time.Duration // maximum duration before timing out read of the request,
    WriteTimeout: time.Duration // maximum duration before timing out write of the response
}
```

(replace `time.Duration` with the actual time)

Then:

```
err := server.ListenAndServeTLS(certFile, keyFile string)
log.Fatal(err)
```

Note `ListenAndServeTLS` always returns a non-nil error.

Comment: thank you. i can use that tls.Config object as TLSConfig parameter as stated at http://www.bite-code.com/2015/06/25/tls-mutual-auth-in-golang/

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. for some reason my certificate seems incomplete by ssl verifier. i opened a new question about it. if possible, please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170775/golang-with-http-ssl-godaddys-certificate-this-servers-certificate-chain-is thanks again!