# HTTP SSL with GoDaddy's certificate - This server's certificate chain is incomplete

Tags: ssl, go, https

in general I got 3 files from GoDaddy:

1. main Certificate file
2. Server Private Key
3. Bundle file

in configured all these files in my Go server in the following way:

```
cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("myalcoholist.pem","myalcoholist.key")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("server: loadkeys: %s", err)

}
    pem, err := ioutil.ReadFile("cert/sf_bundle-g2-g1.crt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to read client certificate authority: %v", err)
    }
    if !certpool.AppendCertsFromPEM(pem) {
        log.Fatalf("Can't parse client certificate authority")
    }
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        ClientCAs:    certpool,
    Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
    }

    srv := &http.Server{
    Addr: "myalcoholist.com:443",
    Handler: n,
    ReadTimeout: time.Duration(5) * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout: time.Duration(5) * time.Second,
    TLSConfig: tlsConfig,
}
err := srv.ListenAndServeTLS("cert/myalcoholist.pem","cert/myalcoholist.key")
```

The web server runs properly, it's currently published at `https://myalcoholist.com:443`.

I validated my SSL using `https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=myalcoholist.com` and it's response is `This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B.`

you can go to this link to see the all detailed result.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following [that thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/golang-nuts/TnwfKyotEIY), and from the [`net/http/#ListenAndServeTLS()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServeTLS) doc:

> If the certificate is signed by a certificate authority, the certFile should be the concatenation of the server's certificate, any intermediates, and the CA's certificate.

Try and make sure your `cert/myalcoholist.pem` includes the CA certificates as well.

That thread used:

```
myTLSConfig := &tls.Config{
    CipherSuites: []uint16{
        tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
        tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
        tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
        tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA},}
myTLSConfig.PreferServerCipherSuites = true
const myWebServerListenAddress = "0.0.0.0:5555"
myTLSWebServer := &http.Server{Addr: myWebServerListenAddress, TLSConfig: myTLSConfig, Handler: router}
if err = myTLSWebServer.ListenAndServeTLS("/home/loongson/webServerKeysV2/golangCertFile2", "/home/loongson/webServerKeysV2/adequatech.ca-comodoinstantssl-exported-privatekey-rsa-ForApache.key"); err != nil {
    panic(err)

}
```

Compared to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38167448/6309), adding a cipher suite is a good idea, but again, try and see if the certificate file passed to `ListenAndServeTLS` works better if it includes the CAs.

---

Sure enough, https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=myalcoholist.com reports grade A, with the warning: “Chain issues: Contains anchor”.
See "[SSL/TLS: How to fix “Chain issues: Contains anchor”](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/79519)" to remove that warning, but [this is not an error though](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/24566):

> [RFC 2119](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119): the server is allowed to include the root certificate (aka "trust anchor") in the chain, or omit it. Some servers include it

Comment: @ufk I have edited the answer to address the last warning reported by ssllabs.

Comment: ahem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173310/godaddy-ssl-cert-verified-grade-a-with-chain-issues-contains-anchor

Comment: You saved my life. I was trying to solve this problem in the previous two days.