# Godaddy ssl cert verified Grade A with Chain issues - Contains anchor

Tags: ssl, go, https

:)

I'm using GoLang to start an https server.

according to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest my certificate configuration is Grade A with the warning `Chain issues - Contains anchor`.

In my previous post ([GoLang with http ssl GoDaddy's certificate - This server's certificate chain is incomplete.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170775/golang-with-http-ssl-godaddys-certificate-this-servers-certificate-chain-is)), @VonC helped me for the second time and also alerted me of that warning.

I tried everything I could think of and couldn't resolve the issue. GoDaddy as a repository of certs and I tried to download gdroot-g2.crt and configure it as `RootCAs`, I tried download the intermindate certificate named gdig2.crt and configured it as `ClientCAs`, but the results are the same.

what am I missing ?

for full code please view my previous stack overflow post at [GoLang with http ssl GoDaddy's certificate - This server's certificate chain is incomplete.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170775/golang-with-http-ssl-godaddys-certificate-this-servers-certificate-chain-is).

Comment: Again, that warning is but a warning: your grade A is safe ;)

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79519/ssl-tls-how-to-fix-chain-issues-contains-anchor#comment135658_79519 did not help?

Comment: @VonC - I know it's just a warning but if there is a way to suppress the warning, i'd like to know how. the url you provided contains an NginX related answer with different configuration of ssl_certificate and ssl_truest_certificate. don't know how to convert that knowledge to go. btw you are awesome, thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: I hoped that if you provide to your ListenAndServeTLS a certificate file which only includes (as mentioned in the link) Site certificate + StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA (instead of the full chain), *and* add to your `certpool` sf_bundle-g2-g1.crt (which you do already), that would be enough to get rid of the warning. The fact that it was about NGiNX is not important here.

Comment: @VonC - first... you are awesome! 2nd.. I just tried to append the intermediate cert (gdig2.crt) to the main crt file, and to verify my certificate. i got down to Grade B with "Chain issues Incomplete, Extra certs"

Comment: Interesting. So that must be something else. I don't have much information beside the two links I mentioned in my previous answer though.

Comment: that's ok. thanks for everything. hope someone else will assist me. have a great day!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GoLang with http ssl GoDaddy's certificate - This server's certificate chain is incomplete.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170775/golang-with-http-ssl-godaddys-certificate-this-servers-certificate-chain-is)